# symfony2 prefill form field type collection

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a 2 form types
In first form type I have a collection form type which uses another form type
in controller I can create e.g. 3 sets to the colection.
BUT!
How can I set default collection row data for combobox, when it comes from relational table (entity) and I want't to have for every collection row another set of data - based on sql and not the same where conditions.

it's not a problem do it with simple setters functions, but I'm unable do it from query, because I still get error "it has to be instance, array given" :-(

thank you